# ocamlgraph.1.8.8: curl error code 403

Tags: setup, compile

I'm trying to install a server and getting an error when running `make build-deps`

```
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - ocamlgraph.1.8.8: curl error code 403
```

anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just successfully downloaded (and installed) ocamlgraph.1.8.8 with opam. I think it was simply that the website was temporarily in a bad mood...

Comment: Ya it was as simple as that. Working now, thanks.